# What is composition as it relates to object-oriented design?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, language-agnostic, composition

I hear (and read on this site) a lot about "favour [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)".

But what is composition? I understand inheritance from the point of Person : Mammal : Animal, but I can't really see the definition of composition anywhere...

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Composition refers to combining simple types to make more complex ones. In your example, composition could be:

```
Animal:
    Skin animalSkin
    Organs animalOrgans


Mammal::Animal:
    Hair/fur mammalFur
    warm-blooded-based_cirulation_system heartAndStuff

Person::Mammal:
    string firstName
    string lastName
```

If you wanted to go totally composition (and get rid of all inheritance) it would look like this:

```
Animal:
    Skin animalSkin
    Organs animalOrgans

Mammal:
    private Animal _animalRef
    Hair/fur mammalFur
    warm-blooded-based_cirulation_system heartAndStuff

Person:
    private Mammal _mammalRef
    string firstName
    string lastName
```

The advantage to this approach is that the types `Mammal` and `Person` do not have to conform to the interface of their previous parent. This *could* be a good thing because sometimes a change to the superclass can have serious effects on the subclasses.

They still can have access to the properties and behaviours of these classes through their private instances of these classes, and if they want to expose these former-superclass behaviours, they can simply wrap them in a public method.

I found a good link with good examples in *[Composition versus Inheritance. A Comparative Look at Two Fundamental Ways to Relate Classes](http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/compoinh.html)*.

Comment: So can I say that: "Composition is when I create an object of `Class A` inside `Class B` (instead of subclassing `Class B` from `Class A`)." ?

Comment: oh. ok got it `w69rdy` answered it later. YES I can say that.

Comment: Ok this makes sense now. For other python programmers who are trying to understand this don't get caught up in the idea that "everything in python is an object" when thinking about composition. Instead think "when I make my class I will use other classes I made as instance variables"

Answer (score 49):

Composition is simply the parts that make up the whole. A car has wheels, an engine, and seats. Inheritance is a "is a " relationship. Composition is a "has a" relationship.

Comment: And Aggregation is a ... relationship.

Comment: Aggregation may be simple composition, or if it is a collection of like things (e.g., wheels on a car), it may be treated as a collection. A car can have four individual wheels, uniquely identified, or it can have a collection of wheels. It depends on usage. If using a collection class, then the collection is itself an aggregation.

Answer (score 24):

There are three ways to give behavior to a class.  You can write that behavior into the class; you can inherit from a class that has the desired behavior; or you can incorporate a class with the desired behavior into your class as a field, or member variable.  The last two represent forms of code reuse, and the final one - composition - is generally preferred.  It doesn't actually give your class the desired behavior - you still need to call the method on the field - but it puts fewer constraints on your class design and results in easier to test and easier to debug code.  Inheritance has its place, but composition should be preferred.

Answer (score 21):

Consider:

```
class Engine
{

}

class Automobile
{

}


class Car extends Automobile // car "is a" automobile //inheritance here
{ 
    Engine engine; // car "has a" engine //composition here   
}
```

**Composition** - Functionality of an object is made up of an aggregate of different classes.  In practice, this means holding a pointer to another class to which work is deferred.

**Inheritance** - Functionality of an object is made up of its own functionality plus functionality from its parent classes.

As to why composition is preferred over inheritance, take a look at the [Circle-ellipse problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem).

Answer (score 5):

An example of composition is where you have an instance of a class within another class, instead of inheriting from it.

[This](http://askville.amazon.com/object-oriented-designs-composition-widely-complex-inheritance/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=5849248) page has a good article explaining why people say "favour composition over inheritance" with some examples of why.

Comment: Not really *an instance of a class[C2] within another class[C1]* but *an **instance** of a class within **instance** of another class*.  The former could be misunderstood as if you instantiated C2 when defining C1, which should not be common.

Comment: The link is broken: *"Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site. We can’t connect to the server at askville.amazon.com"*

Answer (score 1):

**composition**

simply mean using instance variables that are references to other objects.

---

For an illustration of how inheritance compares to composition in the code reuse department, consider this very simple example:

---

**1- Code via inheritance**

```
    class Fruit {

    // Return int number of pieces of peel that
    // resulted from the peeling activity.
    public int peel() {

        System.out.println("Peeling is appealing.");
        return 1;
    }
}

class Apple extends Fruit {
}

class Example1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Apple apple = new Apple();
        int pieces = apple.peel();
    }
}
```

When you run the `Example1 application`, it will print out "Peeling is appealing.", because Apple inherits (reuses) Fruit's implementation of `peel()`. If at some point in the future, however, you wish to change the return value of `peel()` to type Peel, you will break the code for `Example1`. Your change to Fruit breaks Example1's code even though Example1 uses Apple directly and never explicitly mentions Fruit.
for more info ref
Here's what that would look like:

```
class Peel {

    private int peelCount;

    public Peel(int peelCount) {
        this.peelCount = peelCount;
    }

    public int getPeelCount() {

        return peelCount;
    }
    //...
}

class Fruit {

    // Return a Peel object that
    // results from the peeling activity.
    public Peel peel() {

        System.out.println("Peeling is appealing.");
        return new Peel(1);
    }
}

// Apple still compiles and works fine
class Apple extends Fruit {
}

// This old implementation of Example1
// is broken and won't compile.
class Example1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Apple apple = new Apple();
        int pieces = apple.peel();
    }
}
```

**2- Code via composition**
Composition provides an alternative way for `Apple` to reuse `Fruit's` implementation of `peel()`. Instead of extending `Fruit`, `Apple` can hold a reference to a `Fruit` instance and define its own `peel()` method that simply invokes `peel()` on the Fruit. Here's the code:

```
class Fruit {

    // Return int number of pieces of peel that
    // resulted from the peeling activity.
    public int peel() {

        System.out.println("Peeling is appealing.");
        return 1;
    }
}

class Apple {

    private Fruit fruit = new Fruit();

    public int peel() {
        return fruit.peel();
    }
}

class Example2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Apple apple = new Apple();
        int pieces = apple.peel();
    }
}
```

for more information  [ref](https://www.artima.com/designtechniques/compoinh.html)