# OO Programming - Basic Inheritance

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, inheritance

I have two different types of invoices i.e. one for a Consumer and the other for a Business. I have created an "Invoice" abstract class that the Consumer and Business invoices both inherit from. The Consumer invoice references a Consumer Entity and the Business invoice references a Business entity.

Now this works perfectly however the issue arises when I have a collection of "Invoices" in the context class. (Which will essentially contain Consumer and Business invoices). I can't get a reference to the "Business" object or the "Consumer" object. (Makes perfect sense... but I was just wondering how I get around this problem? I would imagine it is a pretty common scenario?)

Do I just create a new method in the abstract class called "GetInvoiceRecipient" that returns a "Recipient" object? The only issue with this solution though is that now I can't retrieve the invoices for a given consumer or given business?

Comment: You can use LINQ: `var businessInvoices = Invoices.Cast<BusinessInvoice>()`. Otherwise, a Recipient sounds fair. It kind of depends on what you want to do. What is the end goal?

Comment: For a question like this, it would be better to include simple example code, instead of explaining your classes in text.

Comment: The problem with casting though is that I have to do a check to see if it is of a specific type?

Comment: @Default: that would fail for all other kinds of invoices. I think you meant `.OfType<BusinessInvoice>()` which will _filter_ the invoices and return only business invoices. Still, he shouldn't be forking his logic. The `Recipient` approach makes sense, as long as both Consumer and Business implement a common `IRecipient` interface.

Comment: @user2909756 `.OfType<BusinessInvoice>()` :)

Comment: I would imagine that LINQ statement will be doing the check behind the scenes. I think I will go with the Recipient interface.

Comment: @dcastro You are absolutely correct, `OfType<>` is the one I was thinking of

Comment: @user2909756, i give a time to your question but haven't find a well specific answer for it, The reason is , your information is not proper, Why you want to access, Business" object or the "Consumer" object?, Which property have you created in Abstract class?, and which type of information you need from Business and Consumer class after invoice is created?. This all answer will solve if you past some code of your classes. it will good to provide you a specific solution for your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just create a Recipient Interface and let the "Consumer" class and the "Business" class implement it.

The abstract Invoice will "talk" only to the Recipient interface.

The Recipient interface will have methods called getName, getEmail or whatever you need. You have to redefine this method inside the Consumer and Business class.

This is a simple solution, but there are many others.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use managing classes for this scenario. That is, a class that contains a dictionary containing a bunch of your classes, be they Consumer, Business, or classes that implement the interface IInvoice. The managing class can have public methods like Add(IInvoice, key) and Lookup(key) as IInvoice

As for your inheritance model, you may want to look into composition instead as it is generally a more flexible option. [What is composition as it relates to object oriented design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441090/what-is-composition-as-it-relates-to-object-oriented-design) though I'm sure it doesnt matter with only two subclasses.