# Classes and sub-classes

Tags: swift

Im trying to connect two classes. I have a class of `CarType` and another one of `Cars`.

When I register a car in `Cars` then I want that car to be connected to a car type from the `CarType` class.

These are my classes

```
class CarType {
    var brand: String?
    var speed: Int?
    var fuel: Int?
    var serviceProvider: String?
    init(brand: String, speed: Int, fuel: Int, serviceProvider: String) {
        self.brand = brand
        self.speed = speed
        self.fuel = fuel
        self.serviceProvider = serviceProvider
    }
}

class Cars {
    var regNum: String?
    var nextMaint: String?
    var operatedBy: String?
    init(regNum: String, nextMaint: String, operatedBy: String) {
        self.regNum = regNum
        self.nextMaint = nextMaint
        self.operatedBy = operatedBy
    }
}
```

I tried to inherit `CarType` in `Cars` but that just confused me...

Comment: Not related but why are you declaring all properties as optional but initialize them with non-optional values? **Don't do that. Never do that**. Remove all question marks. Never fear. You won't get any compiler error.

Comment: Thanks, will do that

Comment: Also, `CarType` should probably be a struct rather than a class and the properties should be declared as `let` not `var` as they are immutable. Your `fuel` property should be an `enum` rather than an `int`

Comment: Just a note, I would rename `Cars` to `Car` because it appears to be a single car. `Cars` sounds like a collection class of some sort. I think @Paulw11 has a good point about the fuel and it might need more clarity. Is it a quantity of fuel or a fuel type? You would want an enum for a fuel type and you might want a double if it's quantity.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Cars` class should have a property named for example: `carType` and this property is of type `CarType`, like this:

```
var carType: CarType?
```

Each `Cars` instance initializes this property in the suitable way through the the initializer or by setting it later.

This is an example of an OOP concept called *Composition*, you can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441090/what-is-composition-as-it-relates-to-object-oriented-design).

By the way, it's better to change `Cars` class name to `Car`, because it models a single car.