# Reference another class using an index vs storing entire instance

Tags: oop, language-agnostic

In a class which needs to "contain information" about another class (sorry I don't know the terms for this), should I store the reference to that other class as something like an integer/id, or should I store it as an instance of the other class? What is this called, if there is a name for it?

As a very basic example, an app where we want to store what a user's favorite restaurant is:

```
public class User {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    // id of restaurant...
    // public int favoriteRestaurantId { get; set; }

    // ...or entire instance of Restaurant type
    // public Restaurant favoriteRestaurant { get; set; }
}

public class Restaurant {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Note: if you think this is off topic, please explain why this question would be allowed and is a highly rated/useful question, but mine is not: [Interface vs Base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56867/interface-vs-base-class) Or at the very least tell me what this is "called" so I can research it more myself. As far as I can tell from Stackoverflow's FAQ this question is on topic.

Comment: In OOP you make objects directly refer to other objects, not to their ids or names. So, if a `user` has a favorite `restaurant`, the `user` should store the `restaurant` instance as one of its properties (instance variables), rather than the name or id of the restaurant.

Comment: One object containing a reference to another is called object composition. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441090/what-is-composition-as-it-relates-to-object-oriented-design. It is possibly the most important principle in OOP.

Comment: Your question is tagged [tag:oop], but you ask "should I?" It's much more "object-oriented" to store references to other objects, but whether you *should* depends on many other factors. In data-oriented programming, storing IDs (and having functions that operate on a higher-level data structure) is more common.

Comment: See, for example, [What is data oriented design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641580/what-is-data-oriented-design) I think your question boils down to "what paradigm should I choose?" which is ultimately up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first variant

```
public int favoriteRestaurantId { get; set; }
```

only makes sense if you are only interested in the `id` and not the other attributes (`name`) of the `restaurant` object. Otherwise you will need some external container that stores all `restaurant` objects and have to search the container for the `restaurant` with the given `id`.

In your second variant

```
public Restaurant favoriteRestaurant { get; set; }
```

if you write

```
someUser.favouriteRestaurant = someRestaurant;
```

this also stores a reference to an existing `someRestaurant`. It will **not** copy the whole object. at least not in languages like C# and Java.

Only if you do something like

```
someUser.favouriteRestaurant = new Restaurant(someRestaurant);
```

the `user` will have its own copy of the `restaurant` object.

There are cases where this would make sense but in your example it is probably not a good idea for two reasons:

1. If for example the `name` of the `someRestaurant` changes, this should also change the name of `favouriteRestaurant`. This will not happen automatically if `favouriteRestaurant` is a copy.
2. It is a waste of memory.