# How to manage different types of Users with different properties on .NET Core 6

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

For example I have two different user, **Student and Admin.**

They have common properties like **Username, Email, Password, CreateDate, Role etc.**

But **Student** has different or extra properties from **Admin**, for example **Image, CvPath, Graduated School, Graduate Year etc.** so how should I build my entity design on this.

Comment: What did you try or what is stopping you?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a base class which has the main properties. Both Student and Admin classes inherits from the base class User. The admin class will have the extra properies in it. You could also add some student-specific properties.

```
public class User
{
  public string Username {get; set;}
  public string Email {get; set;}
  public DateTime CreationDate {get; set;}
  // I am assuming you do not have a Role enum
  public string Role {get; set;}

}

public class Student : User
{
// You can just leave it empty or add something like Current year in school 
// maybe
}

public class Admin : User
{
  public string School {get; set;}
  public DateTime Graduate_Year {get; set;}
  public bool IsGraduated {get; set;}
  // and the reset of props you want for admin
}
```

I hope I helped you!

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

Option 1 : separate `Users.cs` entity to `Admin.cs` and `Student.cs`.

Option 2 : Put all properties you need in admin and student in `Users.cs`.

I suggest `Option 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You may have heard of "favouring Composition over Inheritance" and so I wanted to put forward a case for the former.  Here's my `User` class:

```
public class User
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Username { get; set; }
     public string Email { get; set; }
     public DateTime Created { get; set; }

     public string GetUsernameById(int id)
     {
         return Username;
     }
 }
```

Instead of inheriting the base class of `User`, you could include it in your `Student` and `Admin` classes, like so:

```
public class Student
{
    public User StudentUser { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string CVPath { get; set; }
    public string GraduatedSchool { get; set; }
    public int GraduatedYear { get; set; }
}
```

And for `Admin`:

```
public class Admin
{
    public User AdminUser { get; set; }
    public int Role { get; set; }

    public void ChangeRole(int newLevel)
    {
        Role = newLevel;
    }
}
```

With inheritance, any changes in your superclasses will impact the subclasses, and this can cause a cascade of changes. In addition, the inheritance hierarchy of User -> Student -> Level3 can become overly-complex and therefore onerous to maintain.

With composition you are still able to access the members of the 'parent' classes e.g. `User` in this case.

```
// Create a Student user    
Student student1 = new Student();
User user1 = new User();

student1.StudentUser = user1;
student1.StudentUser.Username = "Miguel";
student1.StudentUser.Email = "Micheal.Coreleone@test.com";
student1.Image = "images/image1.png";
```

How you can access methods from both User and Admin classes:

```
// Create an Admin user
Admin admin = new Admin();
User user2 = new User();

admin.AdminUser = user2;
admin.AdminUser.Id = 2;
admin.AdminUser.Username = "Tom";   
admin.AdminUser.Email = "tom.builder@shiring.com";
admin.Role = 2; // Using integers to keep it simple

// You have access to Admin's methods as you would expect
admin.ChangeRole(1); 

// And access methods of the User class via the User property
string adminUsername = admin.AdminUser.GetUsernameById(3);
```

Here's a great [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441090/what-is-composition-as-it-relates-to-object-oriented-design) on the subject.